# Passing Javascript string var to HTML href tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables, href

Due to limitations, I have to set a URL string on every page header in my website as a JavaScript string variable like this `var burl = "http://www.example.com";`

Now, I have to pass this string `burl` inside an HTML `href=""` tag in the  of my website. I also want to be able to add extra URL elements to the href link beside the burl.

**Here's what the full code look like Javascript + HTML code;**

```js
<script>
var burl = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>

<p>the href below should link to http://www.example.com</p>

<a href="{burl-string-here}/blog/article/">Open Here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help solving this simple issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that in two ways:

- `document.write`
- Via the DOM

#### `document.write`:

In a script tag where you want the link:

```
document.write('<a href="' + burl + '">Open here</a>');
```

That's processed during the parsing of the page, and replaces the script link with the text you output.

Live example:

```html
<script>
var burl = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>
<p>the href below should link to http://www.example.com</p>
<script>
document.write('<a href="' + burl + '">Open Here</a>');
</script>
<p>this is after the link</p>
```

#### Via the DOM

Put an id on the link:

```
<a href="" id="burl">Open here</a>
```

and then in a script tag *after* it

```
document.getElementById("burl").href = burl;
```

Live example:

```html
<script>
var burl = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>
<p>the href below should link to http://www.example.com</p>
<a href="" id="burl">Open Here</a>
<p>this is after the link</p>
<script>
document.getElementById("burl").href = burl;
</script>
```

---

Re your comment:

> what if...I want to manually add an extra element to each link `<a href="burl-string-here/extra-link-element"`

I'd use a `data-*` attribute (`data-extra`, whatever) on the links to say what the extra was. Then get the element into a variable, then:

```
link.href = burl + link.getAttribute("data-extra");`
```

I wouldn't put the extra in `href` because *some* browsers try to expand `href` even when you get it via `getAttribute` (though they shouldn't).

You've said "each link" which makes me think you have a bunch of them. If so, don't use an `id`, but a `class` instead:

```html
<script>
var burl = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>
<p>the href below should link to http://www.example.com</p>
<p><a href="" class="burl" data-extra="/first">First link</a></p>
<p><a href="" class="burl" data-extra="/second">Second link</a></p>
<p><a href="" class="burl" data-extra="/third">Third link</a></p>
<p>this is after the link</p>
<script>
(function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a.burl"), function(link) {
    link.href = burl + link.getAttribute("data-extra");
  });
})();
</script>
```

That uses `Array#forEach` which is on all modern browsers, but not (say) IE8. It can be shimmed/polyfilled, though, or you can use a simple `for` loop. Options in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) (see "for array-like objects" as the list we get back from `querySelectorAll` is array-like).

Comment: 2nd way "via DOM" is the only one I can use TJ but there is only one problem, it replaces the whole href tag... what if you I want to manually add an extra element to each link `<a href="burl-string-here/extra-link-element" `

Comment: @JosephRaphael: I'd use a `data-*` attribute (`data-extra`, whatever) on the link to say what the extra was, get the element into a variable, then: `link.href = burl + link.getAttribute("data-extra");` I wouldn't put the extra in `href` because *some* browsers try to expand `href` even when you get it via `getAttribute` (though they shouldn't).

Comment: can you please update the code snippet you posted with this, so everyone can benefit from it thank you.

Comment: @JosephRaphael: Just did, in fact! :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank you, BTW, can I use id=burl" instead of class="burl" ? thank you

Comment: @JosephRaphael: Not if there's more than one of them. `id` values must be unique on the page.

Answer (score 1):

is it, what u want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var burl = "http://www.example.com";
  $('a').attr('href', burl); 
});
```

ps using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var burl = "http://www.example.com";
  $('a').attr('href',burl )
});
</script>
```